# Can I have the IdP forward a parameter back to my service provider with omniauth-saml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, saml

I have successfully set up SAML authentication using omniauth-saml in my Rails 4.2.0 application. As it's a multi-tenant application and each tenant can define their own IdP, it was tough, but I made it.

When the IdP has authenticated the user, the IdP sends them back to my app at `/auth/saml/callback`, the standard place for omniauth. As long as I'm okay with sending the user to a specified page in my app (say, the dashboard), this all works well.

But what if the user was trying to access a specific page and got sent to the login page? If the user were to sign in normally (email/password), the rails app remembers the return url and sends the user back where they tried to go in the first place.

With omniauth-saml, I'm not sure how to do that. My first instinct is to send a `return_url` parameter to the IdP so the IdP can send it back upon authentication. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was typing out my question, I came up with the idea of using the session to store the return url. Since I couldn't find the answer anywhere before, I'd like to share it here.

I'm having omniauth use my setup phase like so:

```
# config/initializers/omniauth.rb
provider :saml, setup: true
```

I have my sessions controller take care of it:

```
# config/routes.rb
get '/auth/:provider/setup' => 'sessions#sso_setup'

# controllers/sessions_controller.rb
def sso_setup
  session[:sso_return_url] = params[:return_url] if params[:return_url]
  # setup...
end
```

Specifying that the session value should be set ONLY if `params[:return_url]` is set is important - I found that `sso_setup` gets called three times. The third time, `return_url` is not set.

When the IdP calls back to my SP, I simply get the value of `sessions[:sso_return_url]`. If it's set, I know where to redirect the user.